# how can i do Directory Listing Denied for my project folders?

Tags: c#, asp.net, access-denied, directory-listing

i have a project with many folders in it ...

(vs 2008 - asp.net - c#)

how can i do Directory Listing Denied for my project folders when a client try to view those folders using address bar?

thanks in future advance

best regards

Comment: This will largely depend on the web server you are using.

Comment: i have remote access to my web server / windoes server 2003 / how can i configure iis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unCheck the option "Allow Directory Browse" in IIS Management Console for you application.